# How can un-editable firstname, middlename, and last name in account information

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, ce-1.9.2.3

I am using magento version 1.9.2.3.

In,edit account information section, i would not like to provide the fields first name and last name as editable.

How could i change that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Solution,using **a JavaScript make those fields**  as `readonly`.

**Assume that file name is disable.js**

```
   document.getElementById("firstname").setAttribute("readonly", "true")
  document.getElementById("lastname").setAttribute("readonly", "true")
  document.getElementById("middlename").setAttribute("readonly", "true")
```

Then call this files at `customer.xml` under `customer_account_edit`

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addJs">
                <script>js/disable.js</script>
</action>
</<reference>
```

And put this disable.js at ***app/skin/frontend/[Your_Package]/[Your_Theme]/js***

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the **`name.phtml`** from **`frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml`** (you want to find the correct path of your installation).

You can change the text box type to hidden and show the name as a label.

```
<div class="field name-firstname">
    <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname') ?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo
        $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?></label>

    <div class="input-box"><?php echo
        $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>
        //just show the name and make the text box hidden
        <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname') ?>" name="<?php echo
        $this->getFieldName('firstname') ?>" value="<?php echo
        $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>" title="<?php
        echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?>" maxlength="255"
               class="input-text <?php echo
               $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
    </div>
</div>
```

Its just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Open `edit.phtml` from `app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme/template/customer/form/` or Copy it from here in your theme `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/` and find this line:

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getCustomer())->toHtml() ?>
```

replace this line with following code:

```
<div class="field name-firstname">
    <label class="required" for="firstname"><em>*</em>First Name</label>

    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-text required-entry" maxlength="255" title="First Name"
               value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname(); ?>"
               name="firstname" id="firstname" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field name-lastname">
    <label class="required" for="lastname"><em>*</em>Last Name</label>

    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-text required-entry" maxlength="255" title="Last Name"
               value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getLastname() ?>"
               name="lastname" id="lastname" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

Save the file clear the cache done!

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/design/frontend/Your-Package/Your-Theme/template/customer/form/edit.phtml`

Find below code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getCustomer())->toHtml() ?>
```

Replace with:

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->getContainerClassName() ?>">
    <?php if ($this->showPrefix()): ?>
        <div class="field name-prefix">
            <label
                for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix') ?>"<?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?></label>

            <div class="input-box">
                <?php if ($this->getPrefixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix') ?>"
                           name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix') ?>"
                           value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getPrefix()) ?>"
                           title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?>"
                           class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix') ?>"
                            name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix') ?>"
                            title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?>"
                            class="<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
                        <?php foreach ($this->getPrefixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option
                                value="<?php echo $_option ?>"<?php if ($this->getObject()->getPrefix() == $_option): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_option) ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="field name-firstname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname') ?>"
               class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?></label>

        <div class="input-box">
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if ($this->showMiddlename()): ?>
        <?php $isMiddlenameRequired = $this->isMiddlenameRequired(); ?>
        <div class="field name-middlename">
            <label
                for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename') ?>"<?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' class="required"' : '' ?>><?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? '<em>*</em>' : '' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?></label>

            <div class="input-box">
                <?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename') ?>"
                value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="field name-lastname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname') ?>"
               class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname') ?></label>

        <div class="input-box">
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if ($this->showSuffix()): ?>
        <div class="field name-suffix">
            <label
                for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix') ?>"<?php if ($this->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isSuffixRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('suffix') ?></label>

            <div class="input-box">
                <?php if ($this->getSuffixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix') ?>"
                           name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('suffix') ?>"
                           value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getSuffix()) ?>"
                           title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('suffix') ?>"
                           class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix') ?>"
                            name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('suffix') ?>"
                            title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('suffix') ?>"
                            class="<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
                        <?php foreach ($this->getSuffixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option
                                value="<?php echo $_option ?>"<?php if ($this->getObject()->getSuffix() == $_option): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_option) ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Above code will disable first name and last name in account edit page.